# material-ui-dropzone, DropzoneAreaBase not showing the added files preview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, material-ui

I'm trying to use **DropzoneAreaBase** component from **material-ui-dropzone** library. But it's not showing the added files preview. Could anyone know the reason for this issue?

```
<DropzoneAreaBase
 onAdd={(fileObjs) => console.log('Added Files:', fileObjs)}
 onDelete={(fileObj) => console.log('Removed File:', fileObj)}
 showPreviewsInDropzone={true}
 filesLimit={2}
 showAlerts={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the reason for this issue however I've found that using DropzoneArea does work with the previews.

Answer (score 0):

please use this attribute

```
showPreviews={true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is not very clear about this (at least at a first glance), but I think you need to set `getPreviewIcon` and handle a state `fileObjects`. Here is an example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AttachFile, AudioTrack, Description, PictureAsPdf, Theaters } from '@material-ui/icons';

const handlePreviewIcon = (fileObject, classes) => {
  const {type} = fileObject.file
  const iconProps = {
    className : classes.image,
  }

  if (type.startsWith("video/")) return <Theaters {...iconProps} />
  if (type.startsWith("audio/")) return <AudioTrack {...iconProps} />

  switch (type) {
    case "application/msword":
    case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document":
      return <Description {...iconProps} />
    case "application/pdf":
      return <PictureAsPdf {...iconProps} />
    default:
      return <AttachFile {...iconProps} />
  }
}

const [fileObjects, setFileObjects] = useState([]);

<DropzoneAreaBase
  fileObjects={fileObjects}
  onAdd={newFileObjs => {
    console.log('onAdd', newFileObjs);
    setFileObjects([].concat(fileObjects, newFileObjs));
  }}
  onDelete={deleteFileObj => {
    console.log('onDelete', deleteFileObj);
  }}
  getPreviewIcon={handlePreviewIcon}
/>
```